# Reading multiple files/folders with shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am using the read command to capture the files/folder names and further checking if they exist but below script only works with a single file/folder and does not work to capture multiple files/folders. Please help!
Thank you!

```
echo -n "Please enter a name of file/folder you wish to backup: "
read FILE
while [ ! -e "$FILE" ] ;do
read -p "The file ["$FILE"] does not exist."
echo -n "Please enter a name of file/folder you wish to backup: "
read FILE
done
```

Comment: when the user is asked to choose a file/folder, the user can only choose one. But I want the user to be able to choose multiple files/folders to backup

Comment: You seem to already be semi-familiar with the usage of "while" constructs. Apply that same logic after the first read and prompt the user whether he'd like to backup any more files or not, break out of the while loop when appropriate.

Comment: `for f in "${FILE}"; do .. done` is a start, as long as you have filenames without spaces.

Comment: Why are you using `read` at all?  Have the user specify the files/directories to be operated on as command line arguments.  Doing so makes your tool much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking an approach similar to this:

[image]

You can use CTRL + C to force an exit.

> Please note that this should really be an `if` statement like to
>   ensure proper flow of logic as `&&` `||` does not equate to `if`
>   `then` `else` logic

```
if [ "foo" = "foo" ]; then           
    echo expression evaluated as true
else
    echo expression evaluated as false
fi
```

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015

Comment: what about if I am using multiple files?

Comment: This will go until you break it with ctrl + c.  Another option to think about would be to put the list of directories/files in a single file and then perform a while read line file like here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 I recommend bookmarking that site.  It is GREAT!!!